# Select Value form output Python

Tags: python

Hello I have this code.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, req
url = 'https://google-ranking-check.org'
html = req.get(url)
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
imgs = doc.listImg(url = url)
print([img.url for img in imgs])

imgs = doc.selects('img')
for img in imgs:
  print (img)
  print("####")
```

and I have this output.

```
['https://google-ranking-check.org/assets/img/googleranking.png']
{'tag': 'img', 'class': 'img-fluid rounded-circle', 'src': 'assets/img/googleRanking.PNG', 'alt': 'google ranking check', 'title': 'google ranking check', 'html': ''}
####
```

Does anyone know how I can select the 'title' and the 'alt' attribute?

Thanks :)

I tried it with `print(img[])`

Comment: That's just a plain, ordinary dictionary.  `print(img['title'])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your solution:

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, req
url = 'https://google-ranking-check.org'
html = req.get(url)
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
imgs = doc.listImg(url = url)
print([img.url for img in imgs])

imgs = doc.selects('img')
for img in imgs:
    print ('jere',img)
    # selecting only the alt and title attributes
    print('title attrbute: ',img['title'])
    print('alt attribute: ',img['alt'])
    print("####")
```

Output:

```
['https://google-ranking-check.org/assets/img/googleranking.png']
jere {'tag': 'img', 'class': 'img-fluid rounded-circle', 'src': 'assets/img/googleRanking.PNG', 'alt': 'google ranking check', 'title': 'google ranking check', 'html': ''}
title attrbute:  google ranking check
alt attribute:  google ranking check
####
```